# Adjust item in navigation drawer to the left if there's no icon

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

My current problem is i want to move both my 'Log out' and 'About the app' to the left because both of them doesn't have any icon.

i'm currently finding a way to move the 'log out' and 'about the app' to adjust on the left so that they can be align with the icons.

Here is my navigation drawer menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_home"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_pay"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_pay"
            android:title="Pay" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_transfer"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_transfer"
            android:title="Transfer" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_load"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_load"
            android:title="Load" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_link"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_balance_card"
            android:title="Link ATM Card" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_merchants"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_merchants"
            android:title="Locate Merchants" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_logout"
            android:title="Log Out" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_about"
            android:title="About the App" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: So what is the issue? Show your xml

Comment: @Piyush i want to move my  last two item in the left but i don't know how.

Comment: You can set gravity or layout gravity to _start(left)_. Also you can set _android:layoutDirection=""_ for your menu

Comment: @Piyush didn't work.

Comment: can you try setting the icon to null

Answer (score 2):

Separate those sections you want to addjust to the left like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_home"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_pay"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_pay"
        android:title="Pay" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_transfer"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_transfer"
        android:title="Transfer" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_load"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_load"
        android:title="Load" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_link"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_balance_card"
        android:title="Link ATM Card" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_merchants"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer_merchants"
        android:title="Locate Merchants" />
</group>

<item android:title="You title">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_logout"
            android:title="Log Out" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_about"
            android:title="About the App" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: How can i remove the line that is being shown after i apply your code?

Comment: Its like divider/separator